# Recent Badge Awards are moving Associated Questions to the Top

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, badges

I just noticed in [I keep getting lame answers on SO](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15849/i-need-help-i-keep-getting-lame-answers-at-so) in the Active tab, but could find no recent modification. It seems the modification was the awarding of badges to the author.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The modification was that I migrated it from Stack Overflow to meta.

Comment: If you look at http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/781?tab=recent#sort-top, there are four badges listed as awarded very close to each other. Is that due to the migration?

Comment: @John: I don't think they really get transferred, but they do seem to trigger an event that calculates what badges should be awarded.  Those badges are because the question got moved, though.  I say they aren't directly *transferred* because I know some badges, specifically badges that are tied to number of page views, do not get automatically awarded on meta when a question is moved from SO.

Answer (score 4):

Community will randomly bump topics to the top, even if they were inactive.

Comment: Tom, I know that, but that's not what happened in this case.