# Is there any change in reputation penalty for downvoting?

Tags: bug, stack-overflow, questions, down-votes

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Should downvotes on questions be “free”?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90324/should-downvotes-on-questions-be-free)

I just downvoted a question on Stack Overflow. I don't do this very often so I wonder if there was any change in downvoting mechanism because I didn't receive -1 reputation penalty.

Comment: A good source of information: [Recent feature changes to Stack Exchange](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59445/recent-feature-changes-to-stack-exchange).

Comment: @Arjan: Thanks. Should I delete my question or leave it as duplicate?

Comment: just like on all stackexchange sites, duplicates are okay as long as they're identified as duplicates and point to the question they duplicate.  It helps people who may be posting a similar question find the question from your keywords, ditto for search.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Down-votes on questions are now "free", i.e. they don't cost 1 reputation from you any longer. Down-votes on answers still cost the same as before. See [Should downvotes on questions be "free"?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90324/should-downvotes-on-questions-be-free) for the discussion.