# Why cannot questions be sent back to OP for revision?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Create easy way to “send back” bad questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/91774/create-easy-way-to-send-back-bad-questions)

So I asked a stupid question. In retrospect, I can see that it was wrong because I gave insufficient information. However, at the time, I was a bit desperate. It also did not help that I was new to that area. The question was immediately closed. One of the voters did say what additional information could have been useful. The other one tried to put an analogy that was borderline sarcastic/smug etc etc.

Is it possible to send back question to OP to revise it rather than simply closing it?

Comment: [related](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92939/i-think-stackoverflow-should-convert-to-catholicism-so-that-we-may-have-purgator)

Answer (score 15):

That's what closing is.  You can revise it using the tips from the comments, then five votes from the community (or one from a moderator) will reopen your question.

Answer (score 5):

> Is it possible to send back question to OP to revise it rather than simply closing it?

That's what closing means, essentially. Closed doesn't mean deleted. Revise the question and improve it, this will naturally bump it up. Flag the question for moderation attention and ask for it to be re-opened. Or alternatively post a meta question and ask for it to be re-opened, make sure to tag it [support](/questions/tagged/support) and [reopen-closed](/questions/tagged/reopen-closed).

> One of the voters did say what additional information could have been useful.

Upvote that comment.

> The other one tried to put an analogy that was borderline sarcastic/smug etc etc.

Flag that comment as "too chatty".

---

Simple, isn't it?

Comment: meta-tag, that's what I was missing, thanks @BobCratchit

Comment: Posting a meta-question seems like overkill. I'd flag the question.

Comment: @CodeInChaos I don't know about that, it's what we do on Programmers. But SO and MSO are quite different beasts, I've updated the answer.