# Losing points when voting down

Tags: support, down-votes

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does “Reputation” work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work)

What are the criterias for losing points when you vote something down? Sometimes I vote down a question/answer and I lose no points while other times I lose points.  Is it random? Is it time based (after a certain amount of time passes)?

Answer (score 6):

Downvotes on questions are free, downvotes on answers cost one reputation point.

[Read more about it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/91300/can-we-raise-the-awareness-that-question-downvotes-are-now-free)