# Why do I not lose reputation when I downvote posts?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, reputation, down-votes, voting

I have recently earned enough reputation to cast downvotes. And as I understand it, when I downvote (by clicking the down button), my reputation will be decreased. However, I have downvoted at least 3 times already, and none of my reputation has been lost.

Is this a bug, or a change in concept?

Comment: status-bydesign

Comment: @Octavian Damiean : What do you mean?

Comment: "Status-bydesign" is a tag here on Meta that moderators can set when the issue described in the question is behaving that way intentionally and is not a defect.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

**Downvotes on *questions* [are free](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90324/should-downvotes-on-questions-be-free).** This was done in an attempt to encourage more people to vote on questions, and so far, it appears to be working.

Downvotes on *answers* still cost you -1 rep point, just as you expected.

This is covered in the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), where it explains how to gain and lose reputation:

> The primary way to gain reputation is by posting good questions and useful answers. Your peers will vote on your posts, and those votes will cause you to gain (or, in rare cases, lose) reputation:
>
> - answer is voted up             +10
> - question is voted up              +5
> - answer is accepted            +15    (+2 to acceptor)
> - question is voted down     -2
> - answer is voted down          -2     (-1 to voter)

Note the lack of `(-1 to voter)` next to the "question is voted down" scenario.

Comment: @OtagoHarbour: No, sometimes it just isn't worth explaining....

Comment: It's not that it isn't worth explaining, it's that it is *already explained for us*. Read the tooltip on the downvote button. Most of the time, I will add a comment if I downvote for another reason that I consider non-obvious, which is almost always technical inaccuracy.