# Downvoting is not causing reputation loss

Tags: discussion, reputation, rules

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Should downvotes on questions be “free”?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90324/should-downvotes-on-questions-be-free)
>   [Why do I not lose reputation when I downvote posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/93023/why-do-i-not-lose-reputation-when-i-downvote-posts)

If I downvote a question or answer, it causes 2 points loss to the author's reputation and I lose 1 point of my reputation.

Now, for some days now I find there is **no loss** in my reputation when I down-vote a question.

Has there been a change in the reputation rules?

Comment: [Downvoting on questions is now free](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90324/should-downvotes-on-questions-be-free)

Comment: Also, check out the [reputation section](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#reputation) in the main faq.

Comment: Note specifically that it's down-voting of **questions** which is free, but *down-voting of answers is still -1*.

Comment: @M. Tibbits: yes you are right I have noticed it only for questions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not a bug. [Downvotes on questions have been "free"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90324/should-downvotes-on-questions-be-free) to the user who casts them for quite some time (at least since May 12 of 2011). That means that **you will not lose reputation points for downvoting questions**, however the user who owns that question will still lose reputation posts as a result of the downvote.

The hope was that this would encourage users to cast more downvotes on poor quality questions without worrying about sacrificing their own hard-earned reputation. As the statistics show, our hopes were correct and this plan worked as expected.

Downvoting *answers* does still cost reputation points for both the person who casts the vote and the person who owns the post. This has not changed.