# If a question is closed/deleted after I downvote it, do I get my rep back?

Tags: support

I'm simply curious. After all, reputation is taken away to prevent abusive downvoting.

Comment: You don't lose any rep from downvoting questions in the first place.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You do get your rep back if the answer you downvoted is deleted, but you don't if it is locked, or if its question is closed.

Also note that [downvotes on questions are free](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90324/should-downvotes-on-questions-be-free).

Comment: See [this post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43004/how-do-i-audit-my-reputation) for info on recalculating rep