# Inconsistent and confusing rep total in achievements tray after downvoted answer was deleted

Tags: feature-request, bug, reputation, top-bar

Just a while ago, after editing another post here on meta, I happened to notice a green "+1" in the new top bar, apparently informing me that I'd somehow gained 1 rep somewhere.  Clicking it, here's what I was shown:

[image: Screenshot of MSO top bar achievements tray]

Notice how there's no +1 rep entry in the drop-down, or even any set of entries that could sum to +1.  However, there *is* a red -1 from yesterday, caused by downvoting an answer.  (It was still shown in the tray when I took the screenshot, but as I'm writing this, it has disappeared entirely.)

Apparently, what happened is that [the answer I'd downvoted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20273024) was just deleted by its author, causing me to regain the lost rep.  That's fine, that's [how it *should* work](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/110551/if-a-question-is-closed-deleted-after-i-downvote-it-do-i-get-my-rep-back).  But frankly, the way it's presented in the achievements tray is pretty confusing, and I'd argue that it should be considered a bug.

Instead, I'd suggest either:

- not showing rep changes due to post deletion in the achievements tray at all, or
- showing an explicit "question/answer was deleted" entry in the drop-down, with a rep value corresponding to the actual rep change due to deletion (i.e. +1 in this case).

Comment: @ProgramFOX: Ah, good catch.  I think I'll still leave this up, since it adds detail to the other report.  (Also, I never realized before that I could vote to close my own questions. Cool! :D)