# Do downvotes on questions I've voted to close not reduce reputation?

Tags: support, reputation, down-votes, vote-to-close

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Should downvotes on questions be “free”?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90324/should-downvotes-on-questions-be-free)

Sometimes while cleaning up old or severely downvoted questions, I'll do quite a few downvotes and close votes in a short period of time. I noticed today that my reputation did not go down at all when doing this.

Is this because I did too many downvotes in a short period of time (and the system isn't counting them because I hit some limit), or do downvotes on close votes not cost anything?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Downvotes on questions don't cost reputation, only on answers.

Comment: Wow. For all the downvoting I do, I can't believe I missed that.