# Make downvoters lose more reputation

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, reputation, down-votes

Many time when I answered the questions, I just wanted to help. I think I do at the best. And peoples who vote down at me may think that too, that they do at correctly. Some time you may use the feeling, sometime use you the reasoning.

Look at my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9869358/calling-from-jsp/9869534#9869534) finally I asked him that is useful? He said yes. And how? I'm still gets three down vote.

What I think is, the reputation should minus at the same of both. Or the voters should get minus more. Why? Becuase when you have to punish at someone. You should  be understand of the pain before. And each time when you vote down you will have to use the reasoning more than use the feeling.

*Thank you for reading at first until the end.*

Comment: That answer *should* have been downvoted...discouraging that behavior is the opposite of what we'd want to do here.

Comment: *You should be understand of the pain before.* But the downvoter already first had to read the bad post, lost time doing so, and then also loses 1 reputation to warn future readers about the quality. Sounds like the downvoter already feels the pain of trying to keep the high quality of these sites! Also, they may have to downvote many other posts too, hence already losing much more. (As an aside: [voting on Meta is different](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq#vote-differences).)

Comment: Actually, downvotes on questions [were made free to get more downvoting](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90324/should-downvotes-on-questions-be-free/90927#90927)!

Comment: Just because the OP thinks an answer is useful, it does not mean that others agree.

Comment: Down voting without comment is as useless as it is spineless.  If you disagree with an answer, then say why you disagree.  I had a problem integrating R with Java.  I posted a question, got no replies and figured it out myself.  It worked and resolved a problem without causing any so I answered my question.  Someone voted it down w/o saying why.  I think you can discern my opinion.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Original answer was

> Have a look at [my jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DC3zu/1/)

That really isn't a good answer, sorry.

All these downvotes were added to the original answer only

```
-6   22:23  3 events     Calling from jsp
-2   22:23  downvote     
-2   13:07  downvote     
-2   09:24  downvote
```

Take a look at this interesting question about [link only anwers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers)

Answer (score 14):

Down voting is supposed to punish the answer, not you, and there's absolutely no reason to take down votes personally. You answer is bad:

1. It's a link to an external resource, we prefer questions and answers to stand on their own. How much trouble would it be to copy paste the solution in your answer?
2. The original version of your answer was just the link to jsfiddle, no explanation at all.
3. Your answer doesn't answer the question, your actual answer is in the comments.

That last one is not entirely your fault, it's mostly the asker's, but you shouldn't really have answered such a vague question, as more often than not you'll get it wrong. Read the ["how to answer" guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-answer) and all linked material *thoroughly*, to get further details on what we expect from answers.

But the important thing to remember here is: **Don't take votes personally**. Votes are comments to your posts, not you personally, either up or down. No one is looking to punish you, three people just thought your answer wasn't useful and I agree with them. Simple as that, nothing personal.

Comment: +1 `Down voting is supposed to punish the answer, not you`

Answer (score 9):

### Pain?

If you're playing at this for the rep, you're doing it wrong.

*Rep is just a **rough** measure of how much the community trusts you*.

Losing rep isn't a "punishment". Think of it as a sort of "poke" to improve your answer. There shouldn't be much pain in losing rep.

### Why downvote?

A downvote(answer) can mean:

- This is an inefficient way of doing it
- This is wrong
- This does not follow our guidelines
- This does not answer the question
- I hate you/I want my answer to be ranked higher than yours{*}

Question downvotes usually mean "bad question", and are free to use.

### Should downvoters be penalised more?

The people downvoting answers are just taking part in a community process of selecting great answers. They're helping *the community*, so there really shouldn't be a penalty for them. Of course, the penalty is there to just make sure they don't overuse/abuse the ability--since it penalizes the downvoted user as well. It shouldn't be an "eye for an eye", the downvoters aren't doing anything bad from the point of view of the community.

### Regarding that answer

- Even if it helped the OP, other community members must have downvoted it. I don't think the OP himself downvoted it.
- "It helped the OP" does not mean that it's a good answer. Especially a ["just a link" answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers). We prefer answers that explain the situation clearly.

<sup>*"I hate you", if done too often, is automagically reversed. "I want my answer to get ranked higher" is drowned out by votes from the rest of the community, if it's a good answer. So not much of an issue.</sup>

Comment: I read what you said a down vote might mean.  With the exception of the last meaning, a comment would be clearly the preferable approach.