# Down voting bug

Tags: support, reputation, voting

As far as I know each down vote is supposed to reduce reputation by 1 ,but I have down voted some question and answers but my reputation hasn't changed. Is this a bug or I'm mistaken

Comment: Also see [Should downvotes on questions be "free"?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/90324)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only downvoting answers [cost you -1 rep](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/7238/172011). Downvoting questions doesn't.