# Can we get Stack Exchange voting data updates?

Tags: support, voting, data-explorer, data-dump

During some discussion, a very kind user linked me to [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90324/should-downvotes-on-questions-be-free) since I was combing trough SO(comp)/SE trying to familiarise myself with this website and data it provides.

What I am interested in are the graphs and data of that post. I think it would be interesting to see if there is some change in behaviour/use from original data for comparison.

What I am trying to find out is if there is a natural mutation/change in behaviour or data from 8 years ago and now.

**Can we get Stack Exchange voting data updates?**

---

Major thanks to @rene and @Awesome Poodles for providing SEDE queries.

Voting Graphing:

### [image: new graph, Vote Ratios are scaled up to fit]

Question graphing:

[image: new graph, Questions ratios]

Answer graphing:

[image: new graph, Answers ratios]

Comments scores

[image: new graph, Answers ratios]

Comment: Can't that be answered with a SEDE query, for example: https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1102832#graph

Comment: Holy....! I don't know how to do that. I've only went trough tutorials once. I do however plan to go into more details when I have time. But still I think there should be public post/question like this for all people (like me) who don't know or don't have proficient knowledge in SEDE queries.

Comment: There are...literally *thousands* of available queries you can search through.  That's usually the best way to find one that is close to what you want to see.

Comment: @rene, Trends are a bit easier to spot when [the ratio is graphed](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1102891#graph).

Comment: What happened at 2011? Votes dropped by 10?

Comment: @Danilo, you already linked to the Q&A that explained what happened in 2011. [Here it is more explicitly](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/90927/148310).  Bonus question for you: What happened in 2014?

Comment: Sorry i kept reading 8 years ago to 2008. -.- I think 2014 is us leaving the bubble. So by that we could predict that lowest score in 2022 would be 4.37 , and highest 8.66. Is there a way to sumate the ratios to the monthly grid? This is still to many dotes. @AwesomePoodles

Comment: Okay, here's fewer dots: https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1103113/up-down-vote-ratio-on-posts-by-month#graph

Comment: @AwesomePoodles thank you! I was trying to do that since my comment about 2011. I added a graph to the question, joining your query and adding up and down vote statistic. It really seems that around 2015 the pattern starts to repeat after major drop at 2014 due to upvotes decrease.