# Adding a bounty will "break" the reputation feed

Tags: bug, reputation, top-bar

Adding a bounty to a question will break the reputation feed and not show any new gained reputation as long as the gained reputation will not cover the bounty.

I.e If I give a 50 rep bounty, I will not see anything in the bar above as a `+5` as long as I don't get 55 reputation.

This could make it unused for a very long time if you give 500 rep as a bounty. (Minimum 3 days)
Also, I say *break the reputation feed* because according to the comments in [my other question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/208900/show-negative-reputation) this bar is made to show the *the good stuff*.

I noticed this issue when I clicked on the button to get more details on the reputation because I saw upvotes but nothing above and then I saw my 50 bounty decreasing :

> [image]

Comment: Simple fix proposal: Include negative reputation.

Comment: @JohannesKuhn Yup : http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/208900/show-negative-reputation

Comment: @ʞunɥdɐpɐɥd Yes, I have read that. Didn't surprise me that shog is against it. I remember that he is also against sending the suggested-edit decline reasons via global notification. For the same reason. As if comments are "good".

Comment: @JohannesKuhn Shog didn't reply on that question. It's Oded.

Comment: @juergend It is, indeed a duplicate of your question. (I even commented on it wow sometimes I amaze myself) I'll vote to close.

Comment: @ʞunɥdɐpɐɥd Whatever. Someone with a diamond and SE employee.

Comment: @ʞunɥdɐpɐɥd maybe being upside down for so long damage your memory as you walk on your head! ;)

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd Well that's a good theory :P I should get back on SO for a little while...