# Is it the inflation?

Tags: discussion, reputation, bounties

I offered a bounty (50 rep) on [my question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/208900/show-negative-reputation) and it expired. It still haven't got the attention I need for it to change something so I wanted to add another 50 rep to try and get an answer.

Now I cannot start a bounty cheaper than 100 reputation.

> [image]

Is this a bug, by-design or am I just cheap ?

Comment: By design. There are other threads about it, but I can't link easily from mobile

Answer (score 6):

If you check the Help Center topic on [bounties](https://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty), you'll see the following:

> Additionally, if you offer multiple bounties on the same question, the minimum spend doubles with each subsequent bounty (50 reputation on the first bounty, 100 reputation on the second, 200 on the third, and so on).

Answer (score 1):

That's by design.

Bounties always increase for each additional bounty that is posted on the same question.