# Why don't negative rep changes show in the topbar?

Tags: support, down-votes, notification-bar

If I am upvoted, +10 (or +5) appears in the top bar.
But when I am downvoted, nothing notifies me except rep changes.
And if I am on another SE site, I won't know that I got downvoted until I view my profile on that site.
Why is it designed so?

Comment: Short answer: because they don't want you to be notified of anything negative. [Here's](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/208900/display-lost-negative-reputation-in-topbar-achievements) the feature request for it. Until then, the workaround is to open the pane, or notice an unusual upvote notification when downvotes are subtracted.

Comment: It's part of the principal of not notifying you of negative things; but it does mean I don't know I need to improve my answer