# Vote down problem

Tags: discussion, reputation, down-votes

Why StackExchange don't tell me which one of my question or answers vote down received simply up-vote? I only can see these vote down on my profile in `reputation` tab.

Comment: @Aziz Shaikh I find my answer [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/208900/display-lost-negative-reputation-in-topbar-achievements). I'm not an "Established User", "Vote Down", or "View Close Votes" privilege or something. it was helpful. thanks