# Downvotes not shown in Stack Exchange iOS app

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, reputation, notifications, ios-app

Actually, they *are* shown but not like the upvotes.

If you get upvoted, the number of rep. you received is shown in green on the statistics bar in the upper-right corner near the 'mailbox'. It's really helpful as one can see if he got upvoted without opening any other tabs.

If you get downvoted, nothing appears. Sometimes it can be a big surprise to see a downvote after a tap on 'statistics bar' (I'm not quite sure how to call it but hope you understand).

Is it possible to include the following feature in SE's iOS app?

> Show number of lost reputation (maybe in red and with a '-' sign) when getting downvotes on the 'statistics' bar which is in the upper-right corner

Comment: Downvotes don't show up in your achievements box on the website *either*.  Not until there is a positive reputation change again (another *achievement* rather than a disappointment).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Display lost/negative reputation in topbar achievements](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/208900/display-lost-negative-reputation-in-topbar-achievements)

Answer (score 1):

Declining because it was also [declined on the web](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/240060/235711) and I want to follow suit.

Comment: Not the answer I wanted to read, but thanks nonetheless.