# Remove notification that triggers upon final bounty expiration

Tags: feature-request, bounties, notifications, top-bar, expired-bounty

Bounties automatically trigger four notifications, one when three days of advertising remain, one when only one is left, a third when the grace period begins as the last chance to manually award the bounty, and a final one when there is nothing anyone can do about the bounty except maybe flag for bounty fraud.

Why do we even have that one? It's easily as negative as, say being downvoted, [which we don't like to highlight in the topbar](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/208900/display-lost-negative-reputation-in-topbar-achievements), and far less actionable. It's just a handy way to say "Hey, you know that 50/100/500 rep you spent a week and change ago? Well, not only are you certainly not getting it back, but it was utterly wasted and useless and achieved absolutely none of your goals, and there's not a thing you can do about it. Good going. Aren't you glad you decided to put up the bounty?"

To be completely honest, I'd prefer if the rest of the system's philosophy toward notifications was changed to match this, but if not, at least fix this single most egregious example of this sort of downer notification!

Comment: I'm thinking about putting a bounty on this one but I would be too sad in a week's time :(

Comment: @user00001: Yeah, that's pretty recursive, all right.