# Positive AND Negative reputation show as +-1

Tags: bug, status-completed, reputation, achievements-dialog

I downvoted at the cost of 1 reputation, but it shows in the achievement bubble as `+-1`, and it's green instead of red.

[image: Screenshot]

As people have noticed, positive net rep gains also contain the hyphen. The displayed number is the sum of positive and negative, but the `+-` is always there, though possibly only if there was at least one negative value?

Comment: Cross-site post on Meta.SO: [Reputation notification says “+-49” with plus and minus, instead of either “+49” or “-49”](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/386272/4642212).

Comment: It’s not only negative rep. I saw a “+-10” for a 10 rep increase, earlier. Rep decreases are usually not notified, so it wouldn’t be red anyway.

Comment: You're right. I just got +3 in addition to the -1, and it displayed as `+-2`.

Comment: @mbomb007 I just had the same event happen to me, pretty weird.

Comment: **To closevoters:** *It is still possible to reproduce this*. See [this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PrVM0.png) which I took **after** seeing this in the close vote queue. This is neither a bug report for a deprecated feature nor a one-off error that can no longer be reproduced. **Voting to leave open**

Comment: Maybe this is [meta-tag:status-bydesign]?

Comment: @JL2210 I don't think so. Showing negative gains is a [requested feature](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/223006/285610), but to have `+-` is certainly confusing and a bug. If you read the OP above, it displayed `+-1` for a rep gain of `-1`, and it displayed `+-2` for a rep gain of `+2`. So it's showing the `+-` for both positive and negative net gains.

Comment: @mbomb007 I was thinking average gain or loss of reputation, where `+-x` means "positive or negative x reputation".

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This is building out right now.

I had to tweak the code to pass a number around instead of a string, and I mistakenly replaced `rep.IsNullOrEmpty()` with `rep == 0` instead of `rep <= 0`.

Comment: Great, many thanks! A small nitpick: you're [using a hyphen (-1), instead of a minus (−1)](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/74278/why-is-the-minus-sign-not-on-the-same-height-as-the-plus-sign) in the bubble. "Achievements" dropdown is using the correct symbol: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bRFhh.png

Comment: It is somewhat suspicious that you had to write this code in the first place. Why would you need to invent your own string-formatting function? Converting a number to a string with the appropriate sign prefix is a built-in function in nearly every programming environment.

Comment: This was just `<a>+@rep</a>`, which calls `ToString()`. We were never meant to show non-positive numbers, so the basic formatter was fine.