# Achievements dropdown no longer showing downvotes cast

Tags: bug, status-norepro, down-votes, achievements-dialog

The achievements dropdown doesn't light up for negative reputation changes, but until today, if you downvoted an answer and then opened the dropdown, you'd see an entry for that downvote.  It would show as "-1" (in red) with a link to the answer you downvoted.

Today that entry is missing.  In the following screenshot, between the badge and the next positive rep event I had cast a downvote, but it's not there.  It *is* on my profile reputation tab, so it's not a general failure of reporting -- it's just the dropdown.

[image: screenshot]

Could we have this back?  I'm used to that dropdown *including* all events even if it doesn't produce *alerts* for all events.  It should include bounties given, rep changes from removed users, my own downvotes, and anything else that changes reputation.

("But can't you just check your profile?"  Well, if I were active on only one or two sites, maybe...)

**Update:** seems to have gone away (or been fixed) now.

Comment: That seems to have been the case for quite awhile, hence I've long relied only on my reputation (profile) which indeed shows both up and downvotes.  Glad you're posting this question.

Comment: @Namaste not showing the number in the top bar is longstanding, but I'm pretty sure I saw my downvotes a day or two ago.

Comment: Sorry then, Monica.  Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: Might be a regression around where Brian tweaked an  `IsNullOrEmpty`: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/329836/158100

Comment: This isn't one of mine.  My changes to the modal itself were strictly additive (`aria-label` in this case).  We're looking at a possible data fetching issue.  If I understand correctly, you want two listings for the same post, one saying +92 and the other saying -1?  I feel like we've always aggregated plus and minus rep together if it was happening on a single post. If you only get negative rep on a post, you should see it as its own thing.

Comment: @BrianNickel it's different posts.  I downvoted something, and then somebody upvoted the one shown in the screenshot so it got more rep and showed up.  (It got +1 because I was rep-capped before the downvote.)  Previously there were two entries, the -1 for the other post and the +whatever for the subsequent event.

Comment: The downvote was on one of your answers to the question with that title.  It's possible that that item is grouping all your answers together and that's why you're not seeing it.  I'd have to dig further but I feel like something like that is happening.

Comment: @BrianNickel sorry for being unclear.  I'm not talking about the DV I *received* (which is a -2).  I also *cast* a DV (-1) on an answer to a different question; that's the event that's missing.  (You have a diamond, so you can see that DV in my reputation history.)

Comment: Ah, I was looking in the wrong place entirely. I’ll look again.

Comment: Looks like it's fixed (or I misunderstood something), [the downvote I cast is shown here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uMgge.png)

Comment: @BrianNickel it's working again for me too. I'll mark this status-norepro and let you know if I see it again.  (Well, the -1 event appeared, anyway; if a subsequent upvote somewhere causes it to go away, that will be useful data.)