# What is the proper way of reviving declined feature request?

Tags: support, feature-request-process

What would be the proper way of reviving a very old feature request that has already been declined?

If I post a new feature request, it may be closed as a duplicate of the old one.

For instance, *[Display lost/negative reputation in topbar achievements](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/208900/display-lost-negative-reputation-in-topbar-achievements)*.

It has been declined five years ago, and there were recent inquiries on Meta Stack Overflow asking for the same feature. I have also been in situations where I would like to be informed of the downvotes when they occur.

How can I proceed here?

Comment: Re *"...on Stack Overflow"*: Don't you mean *"...on Meta Stack Overflow"*?

Comment: @PeterMortensen Yep, Meta... fixed...

Comment: tl;dr: explicitly state you're aware of the earlier post, rebut the reasons for declining it, and introduce new arguments for implementing it.

Comment: @SonictheReinstateMonica-hog Thanks! I figured something like that from the linked answer is in order. Additional confirmation does not hurt.