# What is the "signal-to-unicorn ratio"?

Tags: discussion, unicorns, terminology

I was reading in the comments of this question: [If downvoting is so important, why does it cost reputation?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/62130/if-downvoting-is-so-important-why-does-it-cost-reputation#comment148049_62147), and came across the term 'signal-to-unicorn ratio' and I have been unable to find out what it means.

Can anyone explain it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's just a play on the common term [signal-to-noise ratio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signal-to-noise_ratio), which here means the number of high quality posts vs. low quality/off-topic posts. [Unicorns](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19479/295232) have many fans under developers (and rightfully so), but have been historically used to derail conversations on Stack Exchange sites, hence they are equated here with 'noise'.